# React Native Apollo change httpLink after Apollo has been initialised when a user selects a different country

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-redux, graphql, apollo-client

is there anyway to dynamically change the http link in Apollo and pick it up from state or local storage. So when the app launches and the user changes their country to France or Germany that the uri or httpLink can be initialised again to include the country. So the uri could change to something like mydomain.com/fr/graphql or mydomain.com/de/graphql

App.tsx

```
const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: store.getState().regionReducer.regionUrl // test uri [mydomain.com/{country_code}/graphql]
  // uri: 'mydomain/graphql', // old uri
});

const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
  const state = store.getState();
  const token = state.authReducer.token ?? null;

  return {
    headers: {
      ...headers,
      authorization: token ? `Bearer ${token}` : '',
    },
  };
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache: new InMemoryCache( {
    addTypename: false,
  })
});

function AppLoading() {
  return null;
}

export default function App() {
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {

      let { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
      if (status !== 'granted') {
        await DeviceHelper.manuallySetLocation().then((countryCode) => {
          setIsLoading(false);
          return;
        });
      }

      // Else automatically set
      await DeviceHelper.automaticallySetLocation().then(() => {
        setIsLoading(false);
        return;
      });
    })();
  }, [])

  let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({});

  if(!fontsLoaded) {
    return <AppLoading />;
  }

  return (
      <ApolloProvider client={client}>
        <Provider store={store}>
          <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
            <NativeBaseProvider>
              <BaseView></BaseView>
            </NativeBaseProvider>
          </PersistGate>
        </Provider>
      </ApolloProvider>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

The first view a user will see is the login which has a select option to select the country which then sets the country code but I can't figure out a way to re-initialise Apollo so if the user decides to hit the submit button to login that it is pointing to the correct server in the right region. it will always default to the original

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change the `HttpLink`. Just like your `setContext` can return new `headers`, it can also return a different `uri` and that would overwrite the one that your `HttpLink` initially was created with.

Comment: Thanks @phry, I had to add middleware so just done it in there `operation.setContext` and changed the order of things below `link: from([authLink.concat(regionalMiddleware), authLink.concat(httpLink)])`, all works fine with my backend now. Thank you :)